# set input text field from combobox using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms, text, input

I want to set a input text field of formular from JSON object, which is value of select option. I have a data in AngularJS controller, after selecting combobox, data is changed, but text field doesn't be filled.
https://github.com/lijunwu001/jstree_with_select.git 
Here is demo link on github.

Comment: put some code please

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: `<select ng-model='vm.selected' required>
                            <option ng-repeat="node in vm.treeData" value='{{ node }}'>{{ node.text }}</option>
                        </select>` node is {id:1, text: text}`<div ng-repeat='node in vm.selected'>
                  ID: <input type='text' ng-attr-value='{{ node["id"] }}' />
                  Description: <input type='text'  ng-attr-value='{{ node["text"] }}' size='35'/><br />
                </div>` Here is the text field

Comment: I've just created repository on git: https://github.com/lijunwu001/jstree_with_select.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's wrong approach. To see your error you can change your code from

```
 <div ng-repeat='node in vm.selected'>
    ID: <input type='text' ng-attr-value='{{ node["id"] }}' />
    Description: <input type='text'  ng-attr-value='{{ node["text"] }}' size='35'/><br />
 </div>
```

To:

```
 <div ng-repeat='node in vm.selected track by $index'>
    Just symbol: <input type='text' ng-attr-value='{{ node }}' />
 </div>
```

It looks strange, doesn't it? It's because you cant bind object to "select" like

```
<select ng-model='vm.selected' required>
```

After your click on "select" option your value of vm.selected is just string, but not an object. And you are doing ng-repeat with symbols of this string.

Comment: Problem solved after calling get_node(id) in jstree using ng-click in select option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ng-change directive

Comment: I've just created repository on git: https://github.com/lijunwu001/jstree_with_select.git What I want is after select item, it update a value of `selected` in controller then update formular with text field. Something like tree on left side on demo page. I can't imagine how to use ng-change in select tag to solve the problem.